# Get value into Ruby code block without it being the last statement

Tags: ruby

I would like to return a value from a `yield` in a Ruby code block. In other words, I would like to pass a value from inside the blocking into the block itself.

```
def bar
    puts "in block"
    foo = 1
    # The next line is wrong, 
    # but this is just to show that I want to assign a value to foo
    foo = yield(foo)
    puts "done block #{foo}"
end

puts "start"
bar do |shoop|
    puts "doing other stuff"
    shoop = 2
    puts "doing more stuff"
    # The following commented-out line would work, 
    # but I would rather not force the programmer 
    # to always put a variable at the end
    #shoop
end
puts "done"
```

What I would like to see for output is:

```
start
in block
doing other stuff
doing more stuff
done block 2
done
```

Is there any way to accomplish this without relying on the implicit return value at the end of a Ruby block? I believe this is possible, because I've seen this type of behavior in `Sinatra` code blocks before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implicitly return values using instance variables, like it is done in Rails:

```
def bar
  yield
  puts "The block has assigned @value to #{@value}"
end

bar do
  @value = 42
  nil # Do not return value intentionally
end
```

This code outputs:

```
The block has assigned @value to 42
```

**UPDATE**

Another nice option is to use helper methods, many frameworks do it too:

```
def bar
  def render(value)
    @value = value
  end

  yield
  puts "The block has rendered #{@value}"
end

bar do
  render 42
  nil # Do not return value intentionally
end
```

This code outputs:

```
The block has rendered 42
```

**UPDATE 2**

Please see an important addition from @Marek Lipka https://stackoverflow.com/a/19542149/203174

Comment: I didn't know about helper methods. Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I must warn you that @Daniel Vartanov answer applies only if `self` in the method and in the method call scope is the same. Otherwise, the block should be called in the context of `self` in method, that is:

```
def bar(&block)
  instance_eval(&block)
  puts "The block has assigned @value to #{@value}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you Marek, it's a valuable addition I'll insert a link to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

One can abuse [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
bar do |shoop|
  puts "doing other stuff"
  2.tap do
    puts "doing more stuff"
  end
end
```

Tap yield to the block, but results in the object that was tapped (in this case, *2*).

It's a fun trick, and occasionally helpful, but a simple temporary variable usually is plainer and easier to read.